# Trigger a Batch Script inside a Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have to Trigger a Batch script inside a Batch script. First I should be able to open the new command prompt and then I should be able to execute the new batch file in it.

This is The batch code

```
C:\XXXX\AppScanSrcCli.exe;
Script C:\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\appscansample.bat
```

The above code was placed in a .bat file

Comment: I placed the above code in a batch file and executed it but it was just opening the application command prompt and not executing the second batch file

Answer (score 0):

you just put

```
start "file.bat"
```

instead of just the file

Comment: Thanks for your help, But the execution of the batch file in app scan command prompt needs a pre-fix called script how can i combine both start and script should i use start "Script file.bat"?

Comment: First i need to Know if `Script C:\Users\Dileepkumar_Gogula\Desktop\appscansample.bat` is an argument of the .exe file, or if it is a different file. If it is, you can just change it to `start "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\AppScanSource\bin\AppScanSrcCli.exe" 
Script C:\Users\Dileepkumar_Gogula\Desktop\appscansample.bat` and it should be fine. If it isn't, put it in front of the _script_

Comment: The AppscanSrcCli.exe directs the windows command prompt to appscan command prompt and in it i have to execute the command Script C:\Users\Dileepkumar_Gogula\Desktop\appscansample.bat . Manually when when i am doing it step by step it was working i want this processes to be done automatically using a batch file which contains these two steps

Comment: Thanks @Modzilla I found the solution i tried /c and & but both of them are not working. I just executed the same command without any space like this then it was working  `"C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\AppScanSource\bin\AppScanSrcCli.exe" Script C:\Users\Dileepkumar_Gogula\Desktop\appscansample.bat`

Comment: I just removed the `start` command which i tried to use before